# Feed Document Library in SharePoint Foundation 2013 with documents on a different server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library

I am trying to set up a shared document environment on our companies internal SharePoint site that feeds the documents from a network share on a seperate master server to six document libraries.  We really like the checkin/checkout feature that SharePoint document libraries provide. I have six document libraries and I want them to pull from six folders on the seperate network share thats on a different server.

Is this possible? Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load them into SharePoint or use a third party or custom solution to integrate them.

Examples are AvePoints file Share Navigator
http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-file-share-navigator/

Bamboo File Share
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-file-share-library.aspx

Is there a reason you can't host them in SharePoint?  You get much more than check in / check out, you also benefit from added metadata and search, version control, and much more (granted you can search file shares, the experience is better with SharePoint controlled content).

Also, remember that SharePoint libraries can be mapped like File Shares, so users can keep a similar experience, in addition you can surface documents thru outlook for offline use (or better a tool like Harmon.IE).

Comment: We want to make sure that access priveledges set up in AD follow the users and also the benefit of hosting the files on our master server is that the master server is backed up and replicated to multiple servers across our organization.

Comment: You can of course use AD Groups to assign permission to assets, but again if you want to leverage file shares, you will need to look at a 3rd party solution to get the benefits.  Out of the box you can point Search at a file share, but that's about it.